# StructureMap (or any IoC) and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, structuremap

Where would one bootstrap StrucureMap in a WCF service? Completely lost here at the moment....

Comment: it more depends on the total architecture of your app but I am curious what other people have to say, unless you update your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dimecast should give you everything you need to know http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/150

from the blog entry:

> When building out a set of services in
>   WCF you still would like to follow the
>   SOLID principles and in order to do
>   this you may want to setup the ability
>   to inject dependencies (via Structure
>   Map) into your services at run time.
>   With WCF extension points this is not
>   only possible, but pretty easy

Comment: +1 for dimecasts reference. Dependency injection and factories are useful in context of WCF IMO